# Integrate AD with local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory

I have a local SQL Server. My computer login is `Domain\myName`.

The local SQL Server instance allows me to sign in using Windows authentication. I am in logins as `Domain\myName`. I am using a third party app that creates a directory that only `Domain\myName` can access.

So I tried to create a credential for `Domain\myName` and then use a proxy to run a SQL Server Agent job that writes to that directory. However, when I right click on credentials, the only location that show up is `<mycomputername>`, so `Domain\myName` does not appear in the identity list.

How can I get `Domain\myName` to be able to run a job with the correct authorization to write to a directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that SSMS dialog is not giving you a picker to select a Domain account, just use TSQL

```
USE msdb ;  
GO  
CREATE CREDENTIAL myNameCredential WITH IDENTITY = 'Domain\myName',   
    SECRET = 'G3$1o)lkJ8HNd!';  
GO  
-- creates proxy and assigns the credential 
EXEC dbo.sp_add_proxy  
    @proxy_name = 'Proxy for myName',  
    @enabled = 1,  
    @description = 'Proxy for myName',  
    @credential_name = 'myNameCredential' ;  
GO  
-- grants the proxy "Proxy for myName" access to 
-- the Powershell Scripting subsystem.  
EXEC dbo.sp_grant_proxy_to_subsystem  
    @proxy_name = N'Proxy for myName',  
    @subsystem_id = 12 ;  
GO
```

[Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy - Using Transact-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure)

Note that the TSQL job step doesn't do a real local logon for the proxy account, so you'll have to use PowerShell or CMDEXEC.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to just manually use the AD in the GUI, but it squawked.